# Why I am getting Laravel error no such table while using php artisan tinker

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

Updated: As someone suggested in comments and answers it worked. But when I try to write `$profile->user` at the end after saving it says null. Can someone reckon why?

I am using laravel 7. I keep getting error: `Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: profiles (SQL: insert into "profiles" ("title", "description", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Cool Title, Description, 1, 2020-08-24 11:58:39, 2020-08-24 11:58:39))'`

When I try to use those commands:

```
 php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.10.4 (PHP 7.4.9 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $profile = new \App\Profile();
=> App\Profile {#3184}
>>> $profile->title='Cool Title';
=> "Cool Title"
>>> $profile->description='Description';
=> "Description"
>>> $profile->user_id = 1;
=> 1
>>> $profile->save();
```

After the save I get that error.

RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

2020_08_24_112130_create_user_profiles_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUserProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_profiles');
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
function index(Request $req) {
    return $req->input();
}

    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function userprofile() {
        return $this->hasOne(UserProfiles::class);
    }
}
```

If there any more code is needed please let me know I will update my question. That's the only error I am getting the one I mentioned at the starting.

Comment: table is called user_profiles? if so you should change your profile model to refer to this table
add protected $table = 'user_profile'; to your model

Comment: it is looking for `profiles ` table but u created `user_profiles` table so u can force  laravel to look in  `profiles` table by adding protected $table = 'user_profile'; to your model in `App\Profile` model

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan Can you please tell where exactly to add this and in what class?

Comment: Look in your `\App\Profile` class. By default, Laravel will take the name of the class and add an `s` to it to look for the table. So `Profile` is looking for the table `profiles`. If that's not the name of the table, you have to specify it as Kamlesh Paul stated.

Comment: As @aynber says you will look in Profile class and before fillable array add this line 
protected $table = 'user_profiles';

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan I don't understand did you mean before the function user()?

Comment: No, read what @aynber says and I just added a field to overtire the default name that laravel took

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan I am sorry, I still don't understand where exactly to add that in my Profile class

Comment: `class Profile extends Model
{
    
    protected $table = 'user_profile';
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}` That's where I added

Answer (score 3):

i don't know if you have created `user_profiles` table in the database but you can do as below in the tinker:

```
$profile = new \App\UserProfiles();
```

if the model is already created

Comment: But if I write `$profile->user` to check it says null

Comment: you should have define the relation on both models

Comment: if it helped you then kindly upvote the answer or accept it so it's useful for others too if they have same query

Comment: Can you please help me with other as well? As it says null after I click save and user $profile->user. I will upvote this and accept it once I get answer to that, as it's still giving error after this

Comment: do you have field $profile->user? or is it a relation?

Comment: I think it's a relation. That's the video I am following on youtube at 1:23:00 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZ5yENzgE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220360/discussion-between-naveed-ali-and-iachi).

Answer (score 2):

You have to migrate the table ( If you haven't created a table let's create one.) :

```
php artisan migrate
```

After repeat your code:

```
$profile = new \App\Profile();

$profile->title='Cool Title';

$profile->description='Description';

$profile->user_id = 1;

$profile->save();
```

If you use Laravel 8 use:

```
    $profile = new App\Models\Profile();
```